# Facebook like button and comments, how to get users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have read a lot of stuff about the Open Graph Protocol and Social plugins.

But I'd like to know if there is a way to programmatically retreive the full list of facebook users who "likes" or "comments" my pages.

For example, imagine that i am the webmaster of http://canalstreet.canalplus.fr/musique/live/canal-street-l-emission-du-05-03-hocus-pocus-en-live-beautiful-losers and i would like to manage people who used the facebook comment block.

Any idea ? It would be interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, just query the "like" table for the object you want to get information about: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like

Comment: Thanks a lot, i realize that my first problem is that i can't get the id of my web page. 

The Graph API give 
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthAccessTokenException",
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource."
   }
}

Comment: Yep, you need an access token before you can make requests like that. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Thank you. The problem posted is solved, so i naturally check the box.
In fact, I can not try until facebook improves its graph (og:type = "article" don't get objects created for them in the graph http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=225263). And it's exactly what i am trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, the graph API is really just a baby. Poorly documentated and very few features implemented as of yet. Will be great soon